# Is macOS installing known bad Certificate Authorities by default?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority, macos

Today I was checking out [macOS security and privacy guide](https://github.com/drduh/macOS-Security-and-Privacy-Guide#certificate-authorities), and when I looked at my keychain, I was surprised to find [Startcom CA](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:WoSign_Issues) and [Symantec CA](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:Symantec_Issues) **trusted by default**. Isn't this supposed to be vulnerable to MITM?
[image: Snapshot of my keychain after manually diabling two notorious CA]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's reaction to the StartCom irregularities is:

> Apple products will block certificates from (...) StartCom root CAs if the 'Not Before' date is on or after 1 Dec 2016 00:00:00 GMT/UTC. ([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202858))

So to verify certificates that have a 'Not Before' date prior to the one mentioned above, they need the StartCom certificate.

With regard to Symantec certificate authorities they've decided on the following timeline:

> Starting August 1, 2018: Partial distrust of Symantec CAs
>
> (...)
>
> Later date: Full distrust of Symantec CAs
>
> ([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208860))

I guess the 'later date' hasn't arrived yet which is why they still need the Symantec certificates.